# Why P and N channel MOSFET is quite hot during braking of 3PH BLDC motor?

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

[IRF4905 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf4905pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e329b1197e)[IRF 3205 Datasheeet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf)[image: mosfet bridge]

I am working on a 24-volt BLDC 3ph drive application.

I have made this design with a basic understanding of p and n channel MOSFET.

In this design, MOSFET gate pulse is in voltage range of 18-20 volt.

I am quite confused about choosing the correct value gate resistor. I found that it must be within 20-50 ohm. I applied many combinations but still, the problem lies the same as the previous one.

I also found that maybe the dead band is not quite enough that will make MOSFET hotter so I changed it accordingly. From 1us to 3.2us. But still no change in temperature.

Please note that the gate pulse is coming from the Allegro based BLDC driver **A4963.** I am also attaching schematic of it.

What can I do to reduce the heating?

- N channel: IRF3205
- P channel: IRF4905
- Driver asic A4963 Allegro

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to remove SHOUTING from the title and post. Add links to datasheets.

Comment: Aside from the shouting... If you are braking a motor, you are removing energy from it.  That energy has to go somewhere, and typically ends up as heat.  Are you using heatsinks on your power devices?

Comment: Which mosfets are you turning on when activating the brake?

Comment: How about turning off your Caps Lock? That's on your keyboard. The text in your question is lowercase so why are only your title and the comment above only uppercase. So you do know how to use Caps Lock. Use "edit" at the bottom of the question to edit it, then you can re-type the title, this time without Caps Lock on. This is about using a computer, you should not be a newbee at that.

Comment: okay, I have done it. but please let back to the problem. when I wanted to stop the motor then the single PWM from the pic controller stops the PWM to the a4963 ic. after that A4963 will stop the PWM gradually. I didn't have control over it.

Comment: You're now very focused on the values of the gate resistors. In the datasheet I do not see any gate resistors in the application diagrams. That leads me to conclude that maybe gate resistors aren't strictly needed (but feel free to prove me wrong and explain why they need to be there). The information that's lacking from your question is the motor **current** and at what **frequency** you're driving the motor.

Comment: currently, frequency is around 15Khz and motor current 5.1 continuous at 12000 rpm

Comment: How long does it take for the motor to stop when braking? How frequent is it stopped? I.e., estimate how much power/energy is expected to be dissipated in the FETs. If it's like 1W for 250ms that shouldn't heat the FETs a lot, if it's 20W for 2s that's a different story.

Comment: Read about deadtime control with gate diodes to speed up turn-off delay then read about “regenerative braking” PWM control on low side then suitable heat sink as kinetic energy is being converted to battery charge. So current limit by acceleration demand cannot exceed heat loss removal design. But avoid cross-conduction.

Comment: _"In this design, MOSFET gate pulse is in voltage range of 18-20 volt."_ Why? Absolute max is rated at 20 V for both type of transistors. How much does the rail voltage rise to during breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am quite confused about choosing the correct value gate resistor. I came to know that it must be within 20-50 ohm

There is no must on this, it should be an appropriate value for your application (0R is appropriate sometimes).

The purpose of gate resistors is usually to control EMI, this happens by slowing down the turn-on and turn-off of the FET by limiting the rate of transfer of charge in and out of the gate. They also help with ringing on the gate itself; the trace connecting your driver to your FET has a small amount of inductance. 
If you consider the gate as a capacitor then this should be easier to understand.

If you don't have excessive ringing on your gate (use a scope to check) then you will want the gate resistance to be as small as possible to reduce switching losses in your FETs. I generally start with 10R myself. Turn-off of the FET is usually desirable to be as fast as possible, so you can have turn-on limited by the gate resistor and a fast turn-off by placing a low Vf diode, such as a BAT17, in parallel with the resistor (anode on the gate side).

> I am also confused about sensing resistor too. is is quite in range or what?

If you look on Page 24 of the datasheet it talks about the current limit. If 5.1A is your desired current limit then:

5.1A = Vilim / 0.0166R

So: Vilim = 305mV

This is outside the range of Vilim that that can be programmed (200mV).

If you remove one of the 0R05 resistors then then Vilim becomes:

5.1A = Vilim / 0.025R

So: Vilim = 204mV

Which is now (just) in-range. You will need to program the VIL register appropriately and also note that in closed-loop control the duty-cycle of your driving waveform determines the current limit.

By using P = I<sup>2</sup>R you can verify the 1W rating for your sense resistors is still appropriate.

Comment: do u see any changes in schematics?  I am also confused about sensing resistor too. is is quite in range or what?